# How to get datacontext used in another xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, datacontext

I have a test application wich consists on two `Windows` and a `UserControl`.

I want to insert the control in each `Window` using the same `DataContext`:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.View"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ControlColorViewModel x:Name="dataContext1"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" Width="64" Height="64" Command="{Binding     
     Path=PressedButton}">Press</Button>

    <view:ControlColor Grid.Column="1" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ControlColor.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.View.ControlColor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">


<Grid Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}">

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ControlColorViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication2.ViewModel
{
class ControlColorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Brush backgroundColor;
    public Brush BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return this.backgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            if (this.backgroundColor != value)
            {
                this.backgroundColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BackgroundColor");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand PressedButton { get { return new RelayCommand(param =>    
    this.SetPressedButton()); } }

    public ControlColorViewModel()
    {
    }

    private void SetPressedButton()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Brushes.Orange;
    }
  }
}
```

Window2.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2.View"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>

    <view:ControlColor />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

When the button is pressed the background in the ContentControl in the MainWindow gets orange, and i want the same for the ContentControl inserted in Window2. Using the same datacontext.

How can i get the same datacontext used in MainWindow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little new to WPF (having more of a WinForms background), but if I understand correctly you could define your dataContext1 in the App file resources and then they both could reference it.

Comment: I've tried this solution in the test app. and it works, i think i'll use it in the project :D. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways. The easy is to have a common, shared model property (CommonModel) and  send it to every ViewModels.
Next step is to use EventAggregator, but to my mind it's too complicated for you..

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look at EventAggregator as soon as i can

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called [Dependency Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163739.aspx) to get your controls to use the same DataContext.

Basically, you need to take it out of the XAML and 'find/resolve' your shared ControlColorViewModel in the constructor for your controls.

Comment: That would work, but depending on his particular needs it may also be like telling him to go buy a Dewalt drill when all he needs is a simple screwdriver :)

Comment: Of course, in my analogy the drill would have to be free and in which case who wouldn't want to go get a free power drill? :)

Comment: Thanks, at the moment i don't think i need to use Dependency injection, but it's something i'll try sooner or later just like the EventAggregator